# How do I add audiences to JWTBearerAuthenticationOptions as they are created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am in the process of securing my public api using oauth2 and jwt tokens.  I have the auth server configured to issue jwt tokens but I am struggling with the implementation of the 'ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption' method.

This code closely resembles the code I am using at the moment, for reference:

```
private static void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = _baseUrl; // The URL of the service issuing the JWT Token. 
    var audienceRepo = ActiveKernel.Get<IAudienceRepo>();
    var validAudiences = audienceRepo.Get();

    List<string> allowedAudienceIds = new List<string>();
    List<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider> providers = new List<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider>();

    // Build the list of valid audiences and keys
    foreach (var validAudience in validAudiences)
    {
        allowedAudienceIds.Add(validAudience.ClientId.ToString().ToUpper());
        providers.Add(new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(validAudience.ClientSecret)));
    }



    // Api controllers with an[Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = allowedAudienceIds.ToArray(),
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = providers.ToArray()
        });
}
```

In this method I am loading all of my audiences and this works great for established audiences.  If a new audience is registered on my server they will not have access until the application is restarted.

How can I add audiences to the JWTBearerAuthenticationOptions as they are created?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this? I also want to add audiences dynamically (to support multitenancy, so i can create consumers on the fly)

Comment: @Verthosa The solution I found is to understand the audiences differently.  I now interpret 'audiences' to mean any API's or applications that use the authorization server instead of meaning the clients that make calls to those API's.  

So I may have 5 Api's that all utilize the same authorization server.  Each api may have hundreds of users, but I will only have 5 audiences (1 for each api).  I believe this is in line with the convention thinking on the RFC .